# VBA to compare two columns and return value for unmatched data

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I'm trying to make the below macro work but it keeps returning every value as "arrived".

```
Sub CompareSheets()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim found As Range

    For Each cell In Sheets("Current").Range("D3:D500")
        Set found = Sheets("Update").Range("D2:D500").Find(cell, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        For Each found In Sheets("Update").Range("D2:D500")
            If Not cell Like found Then cell.Offset(0, 8) = "Arrived"
        Next found
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: you may need some wild card characters in your `Like` comparison. 
see this for all the wildcard comparison operators: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-the-like-operator-and-wildcard-characters-in-string-comparisons-c472b6df-0d3e-4ffc-a21c-bb5721cc460a

Comment: We'd need to see some examples of the values in `cell` and `found`, I imagine. Some examples where it is correct and some where it's not

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, im trying to find the differences between two columns on two different worksheets. if no match is found the value in column  k (0,8) should be "arrived"

Comment: Why not use a VLOOKUP? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: Along the lines of @vityata'a answer below, you may find it useful to add a `breakpoint` into your code on the line `If Not cell Like found Then cell.Offset(0, 8) = "Arrived"`, that way to can see the values of the different variables.  When debugging code, its often easier to look at the specific behaviour in a particular case in which you know what the answer should be, rather than trying to "fix everything at once" in your head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print what is happening in the `If` condition and most probably you would see the way to fix it:

```
For Each cell In Sheets("Current").Range("D3:D500")
    Set found = Sheets("Update").Range("D2:D500").Find(cell, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    For Each found In Sheets("Update").Range("D2:D500")
        If Not cell Like found Then
            cell.Offset(0, 8) = "Arrived"
            MsgBox "Cell is " & cell.Value2 & " and found is " & found.Value2
        End If
    Next found
Next cell
```